# Property 'styleSheet' does not exist on type 'HTMLStyleElement'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have following typescript code and currently getting error on `styleSheet` with error message `Property 'styleSheet' does not exist on type 'HTMLStyleElement'` What type do I need to assign to satisfy `styleSheet`?

```
      var newstyle = document.createElement("style");
      newstyle.setAttribute('data-scoped-style-for', id);
      var csses = scoper(css, prefix);
      if (newstyle.styleSheet){
          newstyle.styleSheet.cssText = csses;
      } else {
          newstyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(csses));
      }
```

Comment: `HTMLStyleElement` doesn't seem to have a `styleSheet` property. Where did you get that code from?

Comment: https://github.com/thomaspark/scoper/blob/master/scoper.js I'm trying to convert this to typescript.

Comment: Replace `if (newstyle.styleSheet)` with `if('styleSheet' in newstyle)`

Comment: I tried it then I get this error on next line `Property 'cssText' does not exist on type 'unknown'` So I did this and worked, but wondering if this is good practice since I'm using "any". `(newstyle as any).styleSheet.cssText = csses;`

Comment: `(newstyle.styleSheet as any).cssText = csses`